# Updating iText sharp in .Net Core - HTML rendering is different

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, itext

In MVC 5 project, i have been using below code to create pdf.

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(headerContents);
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, sr);
```

Now the project is update to .Net Core, so the above code is not supported in Core.
I have been trying different versions to get the exact HTML rendering but there is huge difference in the PDF. Somewhere html tables goes out of PDF & somewhere table borders are not displaying. There is also difference in paddings & margins. Below is one of the code that i tried & failed.

```
HtmlWorker htmlWorker = new HtmlWorker(document);
htmlWorker.StartDocument();
htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);
htmlWorker.EndDocument();
htmlWorker.Close();    
document.Close();
stream.Dispose();
```

https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core

Any idea on How to get the exact PDF in Core as it was in MVC version?

Comment: It is recommended that you can use `Rotativa`

Comment: `XMLWorker` is iText 5. `HtmlWorker` is iText 2 Java or iText 4 .NET. `XMLWorker` does not exist in that iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core (an unofficial version, not endorsed by iText Software). `HtmlWorker` is much simpler than `XMLWorker`, so a difference in rendering is expected.
Both iText 2/4 (with `HtmlWorker`) and iText 5 (with `XMLWorker`) are End-Of-Life and iText 5 only gets security updates.
I recommend that you use **iText 7** + **pdfHTML** add-on. That is supported for .NET Core.